What causes Google API to return blank after first get request?
I'm working on a Python app that integrates with the Spreadsheets API in Google. I've been able to succesfully pull the requested rows on the first attempt but every subsequent attempt returns blank.
I deleted the token.json and tried again, this re-initiated the login process and returned data on the first try. Every try after that, still returns a blank line. This makes me think there's something wrong in the credentials process?  Code below for reference, it is very basic and based on the Google Quickstart guide.
import os

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

SPREADSHEET_ID = "<Spreadsheet ID (verified and working)>"


def main():
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())

        try:
            service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
            sheets = service.spreadsheets()

            result = sheets.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Installed!A2:C3").execute()

            values = result.get("values", [])
            
            for row in values:
                print(row)
                
        except HttpError as error:
            print(error)

def test():
    print('success')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Moved to a new PC from my work system to account for local policies.
Deleted and re-initiated the token.json process.
Verified settings in API setup/test users.
Ran via elevated CMD and via VS Code.
Altered range to avoid possible conflicts with data types.
After a lengthy amount of time has elapsed,(at least 10 - 15 minutes) the app will sometimes run again successfully, but only for one pull, then returns blank lines again.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand I've been able to succesfully pull the requested rows on the first attempt but every subsequent attempt returns blank.. You run your script for the first time, values = result.get("values", []) returns the correct values. When you run your script again, values = result.get("values", []) returns no values. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, that's correct.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution.
